# Javascript wait/delay function doesn't work when more than 5 sec

Tags: javascript, async-await, electron, delay, sleep

I thought I had a nice and working delay function but it seems to stop working after I pass anything more than 5000 ms into it. Im using Electron but that shouldn't be an issue with this.

```js
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, t)
  });
}

async function run() {
  console.log('before');
  await delay(10000)
  console.log('after');
}

run();
```

The expected output is clearly

```
'before'
'after'
```

However, `'after'` logs only when I pass 0 - 5000. What could be causing this? Is the promise somehow getting garbage collected?

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: It seems to work fine for me too: https://jsfiddle.net/L7vj3778/. Perhaps there is something elsewhere in your environment that is causing the issue?

Comment: Could you provide a runnable snippet/fiddle that demonstrates the issue?